# When manually refreshing the page not found in server

Tags: angular, typescript

am working on angular9 application, when am refreshing the URLs manually after login in a page not found error occurs. Tried some solutions mentioned below but not working for me

Add imports:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

In NgModule provider:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

In my application i tried:-

app.module.ts:-

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

app-routing.module.ts:-

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Still not working!

Also need to know how to add this hashing foe a separate route:-

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)], // how to do hashing true 
                                              here?
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: DId you stop and start the server again after making these changes? Sometimes, that can be the issue.

Comment: No haven't restart server, is it mandatory?

Comment: okay your using hash routing strategy. the code looks good to me. most likely in the routes or something else

Comment: No. Its not necessary but sometimes issue can get resolved it doing so. Code wise, I don't think there is any problem

Comment: may i know how to add hashing true here , 

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

Comment: can you please show the url that you are refresh after login page?

Comment: yeah it is working now.. Thanks Guys for helping!

Comment: but for a particular route it is not working and it has separate route  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)], but i cannot add hashing true here as it will take one argument only!